# Inconsistencies with Grails 2.2.1 plugin dependency resolution

Tags: grails, dependencies, grails-plugin

After I upgraded to Grails 2.2.1 my inline plugin directives have stopped working. 
For example the following does not resolve the plugin.

`grails.plugin.location.'commons' = "../../common/commons-upgrade"`

I followed the guide 
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html
 which says to add the following 
`legacyResolve true` to the BuildConfig.groovy but it still doesn't work.

Also the guide claims that

> Grails 2.2 no longer uses the BuildConfig of the plugin for dependency resolution and only uses data provided by POMs

Although I have found that the application neither requires a POM and by default still uses the BuildConfig for plugin resolution. Given that Grails depends on some plugins by default I would expect the create-app to automatically generate a POM and for it to be used by default.

Can someone resolve my confusion with dependency resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`grails generate-pom`

to create a pom for your plugin which can be used for deployment, however that doesn't fix the problem you're seeing at the moment.

The only way I've found to get around it is to set legacyResolve true in the build config as per http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/upgradingFromPreviousVersionsOfGrails.html

Hopefully that will be fixed soon.